# How to add textBox programmatically into Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, grid-layout

I have a WPF Grid I want to insert some images into at runtime.    The MSDN at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

gives this example, using text not images but I assume the concept is the same . . .

```
// Create the application's main window
mainWindow = new Window();
mainWindow.Title = "Grid Sample";

// Create the Grid
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
myGrid.Width = 250;
myGrid.Height = 100;
myGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
myGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
myGrid.ShowGridLines = true;

// Define the Columns
ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);

// Define the Rows
RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef3 = new RowDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef4 = new RowDefinition();
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef3);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef4);

// Add the first text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
txt1.Text = "2005 Products Shipped";
txt1.FontSize = 20; 
txt1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
Grid.SetColumnSpan(txt1, 3);
Grid.SetRow(txt1, 0);
```

The grid gets drawn fine but no text appears.  And I don't understand it anyway because the Text part of the example doesn't reference "myGrid" - how does it know what grid is being referred-to?    I tried replacing Grid" with "myGrid" but then the compiler just says "*cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead*".

So how **do** I insert an item into an arbitrary Grid coordinate at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a crucial line from that example:

```
myGrid.Children.Add(txt1);
```

That actually puts the text block into the layout (by adding it to the grid).

The reason you cant use `myGrid` in the function calls is that `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` are **Attached Properties** you don't set them the way you would think (or set them up in XAML the way you would think). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589023(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information on how this works (linked to the SetColumn function).

The "Grid" control looks at that attached property for its children and places the item accordingly, thus you don't need a reference to `myGrid1` when setting the Column/Row.

MSDN for Attached Properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my missing line!!   But I'm still confused about the attached properties.  When we use _Grid.SetColumnSpan()_ without specifying a specific instance of Grid how does it know which instance of Grid I'm referring to?   What if my app has 3 Grids in it?

Comment: @user316117 It doesn't! It just sets the "Grid.ColumSpan" attached property for that element. Then when the grid is laying out its children, it looks at that property when positioning and sizing. Does that make sense?

Comment: So it's a property of txt1, not the Grid element?  It's putting a label on txt1 saying "if added to a Grid put this text in this column"?  Is that a good way to think about it?

Comment: @user316117 Thats right. Added the documentation for attached properties to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that that example is missing is

```
Grid.Children.Add(txt1);
```

at the very end. Basically, you use `Grid.SetRow`, `Grid.SetColumn`, `Grid.SetRowSpan` and `Grid.SetColumnSpan` on your control to set where it will be in the grid and how many cells it will take up, and then all you have to do is `Add` it to the grid's `Children` for it to actually show up.

So if you want to add an arbitrary control into your `Grid` at runtime, just use these functions and you should be set.